# LightSwitch Programmatic Move between screens

Tags: lightswitch-2012

First Attempt at LightSwitch.
Using HTML Client.
Hierarchical data, displayed in screens through Parent->Child relationships using Item Tap.

At the last child detail screen (Units Detail) I want to move to a screen showing the 'readings' for the tapped unit.
The database structure prevents a normal ERM '1 to many' relationship 'unit' -> 'readings' being formed so LightSwitch cannot go further with a 'Unit' detail screen showing readings as additional data.

I need to capture the UnitId of the tapped unit and open the reading screen by passing that value in as a parameter. (Reading screen will be based on parameterised query)

I have been unable to find code that shows one LightSwitch screen calling another.
I figure that I need  write my Own tap method but haven't got a feel about what goes in it.

The 'how do I series' of videos from Beth won't play on my machine so please don't suggest watching them.

Would appreciate any pointer or code snippet that demos how to do this.

thanks
Bob

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1695aaea-ece8-4050-8850-7971aa50af50/html-client-usage-of-myappshowscreen-function?forum=lightswitch

Comment: If you have any questions refer to Huy Nguyen blog he have addressed most of the issue with lightswitch.